# Какое преимущество кластера перед одним сервером?

Tags: база-данных, сервер, железо, кластер, кластеризация

Примерные данные по кластеру:
1 сервер - Балансировщик приложении
2 сервера - Сервер приложении
2 сервера - Сервер БД
1 сервер - Сервер поиска и хранении

Детальной разницы и преимущества не знаю, поэтому хотелось бы узнать у более компететных участников форума.

Что можно почитать на эту тему? Куда смотреть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тема слишком обширная. Много чего можно посоветовать. Но банально.

Есть у вас 1 сервер БД, к примеру. Что будет, если он упадёт? Всё плохо. Во-первых, вы данные потеряете (по крайней мере данные с прошлого бекапа). Во-вторых, ваши сервисы остальные работать не смогут без базы.

Теперь же, предположим, у вас 3 ноды базы в кластере и настроена репликация (то есть, дублирование данных). Если 1 нода выйдет из строя, то кластер продолжит работу. Если у вас 5 нод, то кластер может выдержать потерю 2 нод.

Это, если кратно. Естественно, всё зависит от архитектуру СУБД. Что хорошо для riak, то не очень для mongodb и т.п. Но в целом кластеризация помогает сохранить работоспособность даже при потере каких-то узлов в системе.

Плюс, это даёт распределение нагрузки, если хорошо всё связать с loadbalancer'ом.

В плане репликации в целом там обычно две модели:

- **master-master**. Сложно реализуемый вариант. Обычно при этом попираются принципы ACID. У нас, к примеру, использует RethinkDB, там как раз master-master. Как даунсайд - отсутствие транзакций и т.п. плюшек, которые обычно есть в реляционных базах. В таком варианте все ноды могут писать данные, от этого все проблемы.
- **master-slave**. Проще реализовать. Пишет только master и пушит в слейвы. Со слейвов можно только читать. Отсюда простота реализации. Если выходит из строя мастер, то обычно слейвы голосует за то, кто будет новым мастером. Если всё удачно, то слейв становится мастером, а все остальные слейвы переключаются на него.

Книги могу посоветовать в большей степени только на английском:

- [Highscalability](http://highscalability.com/) (:
- [NoSQL Guide](http://martinfowler.com/nosql.html) от Мартина Фаулера.
- [Best practices по архитектуре в облаке от Amazon](http://jineshvaria.s3.amazonaws.com/public/cloudbestpractices-jvaria.pdf).
- Ещё советую читать статьи про конкретные реализации (по конкретной СУБД). Поможет [этот](http://nosql-database.org/) сайт.
- Как уже сказал, лучше читать статьи про конкретные реализации: [всё про репликацию в MaridDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/replication-cluster-multi-master/), [репликация и кластеризация в Postres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling).
- Про [Scalability](http://www.possibility.com/wiki/index.php?title=Scalability).

Comment: Если Вам не будет трудно, могли бы подсказать что смотреть, что почитать ?

Comment: @Goldy я могу только подсказать ссылки на английские тексты. Подойдёт?

Comment: Да, конечно подойдет.

Comment: @Goldy обновил ответ, добавил парочку интересных ресурсов.